# Ocassional Error loading script

Tags: javascript, php, css

I have some sites that I've been creating and they work fine but sometimes the pages will load and look like this

[image]

It'll usually work fine again if I reload the page but the problem is annoying and occurs around 20% of the time.

Answer (score -1):

i went to that url and got it the first time, but then was not able to reproduce it.
do you have load sharing with multiple servers?
watch the network tab in the inspector for anything and post back what you see.

Comment: there are differences in the header response. 
the bad page has these headers
`HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 29 Mar 2017 19:24:48 GMT
Server: Apache
Link: <http://currencyexchangemarkham.ca/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/", <http://currencyexchangemarkham.ca/?p=3334>; rel=shortlink
W: W
g: g
A: A
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 16137
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=93
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 :`

the good page has...

Comment: the good page has...
`HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 29 Mar 2017 19:30:49 GMT
Server: Apache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Last-Modified: Wed, 29 Mar 2017 19:24:51 GMT
ETag: "499f730-3ef2-54be387cb5189;54be15db25451"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 16114
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Encoding: gzip`

Comment: differences are...
bad page has no etag, and no last modified date, and it has 4 extra fields.
the 4 extra fields are.. Link, W, g, A

Comment: by the way it reproduced when I went to a new page (hitting refresh never reproduced), in this case i went to the contact us page